# Inherit params seems not to work when importing from another library

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have a `renderFunction` with the following signature:

```r
renderSemanticTable <- function(expr, 
                                format = c("striped", "selectable"),
                                type = c("auto", "definition", "structured"),
                                rownames = FALSE,
                                colnames = TRUE,
                                align = NULL,
                                color = NULL,
                                invert_color = FALSE,
                                stacking = c("auto", "unstackable", "tablet stackable"),
                                column_sizing = "auto",
                                fixed = FALSE,
                                size = c("auto", "small", "large"),
                                escape = TRUE)
```

In my documentation I wanted to get some parameter docs from `shiny::renderTable`. Thus, I added

```r
#' @inheritParams shiny::renderTable
```

to my `roxygen2` block. However, when looking into the reuslting `.Rd` file, I do not find any entry for `rownames`.

Looking into the [source code of `renderTable` on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/300fb217d113e846d4f2ad8ccb02e9cb4e5b7322/R/render-table.R#L34C1-L35C23) I see that `rownames` is documented together with `colnames`.

Is this an issue? In any case I am not able to get the documentation of rownames into my `.Rd` file. What is amiss? Is it a bug and I should file an issue?